# Issue with spring security encode password from old version to new version

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a database with passwords encoded by **spring security core 1.2.7.3**.

Now I've created a new REST application using

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0", {
    excludes ('spring-security-core')
}
```

Now I'm able to login if I encode a password with my new application, but I'm not able to login with previous encoded passwords stored in the database.

So, my question is how to make it to work the encode password to support for both version of sprig security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the "what's new in version 2" documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/newInV2.html):

> bcrypt by default
>
> The default password hashing algorithm is now bcrypt since it is a very robust hashing approach. PBKDF2 is similar and is also supported. You can still use any message digest algorithm that is supported in your JDK; see this Java page for the available algorithms.
>
> New applications should use bcrypt or PBKDF2, but if you didn't change the default settings in previous versions of the plugin and want to continue using the same algorithm, use these settings:
>
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-256'
>       grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1